# which key-value data structures should i use? quick retrieval by value, and quick retrieval by key

Tags: java, c++, data-structures

i have a set of pairs of data: (key, value). **they key is unique, and so is the value** (there will not be two equal values, nor two equal keys). Like this...

`dataStructure = {"ph", 0}, {"f", 1}, {"o", 2}, {"th", 3} ...`

(the index is arbitrary, but it must be accessible)

is there any data structure that (efficiently) allows me to retrieve the key of an item, given a value? like this:
`dataStructure.getByValue("ph") -> 0` and `dataStructure.getByKey(0) -> "ph"`

I've been reading about hashmaps, but this is not the structure i'm looking for: hashmaps are for non-unique value items, so i can't retrieve the key given a value.

I'd like to use this as a codifier, "photho" would be codified into 0230, and this would be decodified as "photho" again.

I'd like to know the name of the data structure... it doesn't matter the language...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Boost. bimap](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/bimap/doc/html/index.html)  should suit you.

> Boost.Bimap is a bidirectional maps library for C++. With Boost.Bimap
>   you can create associative containers in which both types can be used
>   as key. A bimap can be thought of as a combination of a
>   std::map and a std::map.

Answer (score 1):

Use two [maps](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/).  Combine them into a single class, so that you can have  your two `get` methods on the same object.

Comment: this is a good answer... but i'm choosing Johan's answer, because he gave me the name of the data structure